# change PHP session id on link click

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create an HTML link that changes the PHP session id.  Basically I need to call the session_regenerate_id(); when a link is clicked.  The problem is that it can't run on the page that I am linking to.  There is an upload form that reloads after upload so the function cannot be on the page I am linking to.

Can I do an AJAX post to a separate PHP file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your php file called regenerate.php:

`<?php session_regenerate_id(); ?>`

And then with jquery.

```
$.POST('url/to/regenerate.php', function() {
   // callback
});
```

Then to run it:

```
$(function() {
      $('#postNew').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // stops the link from going anywhere
        $.POST('url/to/regenerate.php', function() {
          // callback
        });
     });

});
```

Comment: Awesome!  One question - how do I run this when <a href id="postNew"> is clicked?

Comment: hmm..  That looks right, but I get an error saying .POST is not a function